# DDD, EF and Referential Integrity

Tags: entity-framework, domain-driven-design, aggregate, navigation-properties

Ok so I have my roots defined.  Entities inside a root are allowed references to other entities inside the same root, but not outside.  There they can only have the identity or the related entity.  This is all great.

But, I'm using EF5 and navigation properties are getting in the way.  I really want to only define navigation properties where entities are inside the aggregate.  But how can I apply some referential integrity where related entities are in different aggregates?  Is the only option to add FKs manually using migrations?

And again, but... this is going to cause a bit of a problem because I want to be able to have ReadOnlyRepositories for fetching aggregated data from all over the place.  I don't want to get into CQRS as there is too much of a leap there I feel.  Am I stuck needing a second bounded context with a new set (or maybe derived set) of entities with extra navigation properties defined?   All so i can write queries that pull data from more than one root?

Comment: CQRS means a big leap? For crying out loud, it just means to have a read model besides the domain model.

Comment: Since your database is responsible for the referential integrity can you not simply ignore the relationship in the EF model?  So there would be no way of navigating in the data model either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needing referential integrity usually indicates a deeper issue. Why do you need the entity identifier to exist in both tables? What is being held consistent that way? And why isn't that modeled explicitly? These questions are not as important as the answer to them. Also realize that by just using other technology over the same db schema (and proper indexes) many of your problems could go away. Who knows, you just might be doing CQRS at that point in time.